# Create Numeric Keyboard Firemonkey Delphi and Dynamic create button with Font are not working

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm doing a touch system (Windows) that needs numeric keyboard to insert user, manual entry, password, exit system. I prefered to create Button, but the attribute Font are not working.

I created a class:

```pascal
unit uKeyboard;

interface

uses
  FMX.Edit, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Layouts, SysUtils;

type
  TKeyboard = class(TObject)
    btnk  : array [0..9] of TButton;
    btnx  : TButton;
    btnbs : TButton;
    edtk  : TEdit;
    procedure OnClickB (Sender : TObject);
    procedure OnClickX (Sender : TObject );
    procedure OnClickBS (Sender : TObject );
  public
    constructor Create (var GLayout1 : TGridLayout; var EdtText : TEdit);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TKeyboard.Create(var GLayout1: TGridLayout; var EdtText: TEdit);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  edtk := EdtText;
  GLayout1.ItemWidth := Round(GLayout1.Width/3);
  GLayout1.ItemHeight := Round(GLayout1.Height/4);
  for i := 9 downto 0 do
  begin
    btnk[i] := TButton.Create(GLayout1);
    with btnk[i] do
    begin
      Parent := GLayout1;
      TextSettings.Font.Size := 40;
      Text := IntToStr(i);
      OnClick := OnClickB;
    end;
  end;
  ...
```

Inside Main Unit:

```pascal
uses
  uKeyboard, ...;

var
  Keyboard : TKeyboard;

// OnClickButton

Keyboard := TKeyboard.Create(GridLayout4,EdtRelease);
```

The Font is not 40:

[image]

Comment: Make sure StyledSettings for the buttons exclude size. Not enough code posted to reproduce - try and create an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation:

[Setting Text Parameters in FireMonkey: Using the StyledSettings Property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_Text_Parameters_in_FireMonkey#Using_the_StyledSettings_Property)

> When changing text representation properties of the [TTextSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TTextSettings) type objects, remember that when you are changing the value of a property (of the `TextSettings.Font.Size` property in the previous example), then **the actual changing of the object's view happens only if the [ITextSettings.StyledSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings.StyledSettings) property does not contain the [TStyledSetting.Size](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TStyledSetting) constant**. The ["Relation between TStyledSetting constants and TTextSettings properties"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings) table shows which [TStyledSetting](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TStyledSetting) constants control handling of the [TTextSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TTextSettings) text representation properties.

So, in order to set a value to the `TButton.TextSettings.Font.Size`, you need to remove the `TStyledSetting.Size` flag from the `TButton.StyledSettings` property, eg:

```pascal
btnk[i] := TButton.Create(GLayout1);
with btnk[i] do
begin
  Parent := GLayout1;
  StyledSettings := StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Size]; // <-- add this
  TextSettings.Font.Size := 40;
  Text := IntToStr(i);
  OnClick := OnClickB;
end;
```